# Get PID of currently executed application

Tags: xcode, memory, malloc, malloc-history

While debugging on XCode, I wanted to find out how to get the PID of the currently debugged application, from this sample;

2012-07-02 16:02:02.124 appname[14995:700]

which one of those is the pid? i need to get the pid because i wanted to check a memory leak using malloc_history which requires the pid of the application,

i tried the ff: combinations,

```
shell malloc_history
 app 
 appname.app
 appname[14995]
 appname[14995:700]
 14995
 14995:700
 700
0x000000 (address)
```

but I always get the process does not exist in the history
tbe (malloc_history cannot find a process you have access to which has a name like "")

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Cocoa you can use:

```
[NSProcessInfo processInfo].processIdentifier;
```